# "Available from" versus "available on"

Tags: meaning, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between *available from* and *available on*?

Do the following sentences have a different meaning?

> Check the information available from [URL of a web page].
>   Check the information available on [URL of a web page].

My interpretation is that they mean, respectively:

- Check the information you find in that page, and in any page with a link in that page.
- Check the information you find in that page.

Is that a correct interpretation? Is it the current meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how literally you want to take it. Strictly speaking, as the address is to a specific page (info.html), you could say that it was just that page.

However, it is reasonable to assume that if the information linked to from within that page is relevant then it might apply in the original sentence, especially if that information is still on the same overall site.

Comment: In the first case, would not the sentence be _check the information available on […]_?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.